# At least 1 checkbox of each group?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to apply a new rule into my current jQuery validate that will check if each of my groups have at least 1 checkbox checked.

My difficult is that I cannot change the checkboxes names.

Here is my current jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#docContainer').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            EMAIL: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            FNAME: {
                required: true
            },
            POSTCODE: {
                digits: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            mark1: {
                required: function(elem)
                {
                    if ($('input[name="group[20349][1]"]:checked').length > 0 ||
                        $('input[name="group[20349][2]"]:checked').length > 0 ||
                        $('input[name="group[20349][3]"]:checked').length > 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            },
            mark2: {
                required: function(elem)
                {
                    if ($('input[name="group[20353][1]"]:checked').length > 0 ||
                        $('input[name="group[20353][2]"]:checked').length > 0 ||
                        $('input[name="group[20353][3]"]:checked').length > 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            },
            mark3: { 
                required: function(elem)
                {
                    if ($('input[name="group[20357][1]"]:checked').length > 0 ||
                        $('input[name="group[20357][2]"]:checked').length > 0 ||
                        $('input[name="group[20357][3]"]:checked').length > 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            FNAME: "<b style='color:#FFFFFF'>Please fill your first name...</b>",
            EMAIL: {
                required: "<b style='color:#FFFFFF'>We need your email address to contact you!</b>",
                email: "<b style='color:#FFFFFF'>Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com</b>"
            },
            POSTCODE: {
                digits: "<b style='color:#FFFFFF'>Post Code must be numbers only...</b>",
                minlength: "<b style='color:#FFFFFF'>Post Code must be at least 4 digits...</b>"
            },
            mark1: "<b style='color:#FFFFFF'>You must CHECK at least 1 option for Type Of Property...</b>",
            mark2: "<b style='color:#FFFFFF'>You must CHECK at least 1 option for Bedrooms...</b>",
            mark3: "<b style='color:#FFFFFF'>You must CHECK at least 1 option for Price Range...</b>"
        }
    });
});  
</script>
```

`mark1`, `mark2`, `mark3` are the created fields to fit as the rule for each group, as you can see inside, my checkboxes have unique name for each and I cannot change that.

Group 1 aka `mark1` is composed of: `group[20349][1]`, `group[20349][2]`, `group[20349][3]`
Group 2 aka `mark2` is composed of: `group[20353][1]`, `group[20353][2]`, `group[20353][3]`
Group 3 aka `mark3` is composed of: `group[20357][1]`, `group[20357][2]`, `group[20357][3]`

My issue is that the rule does not work, it triggers for name, email, but doesn't trigger for the checkboxes when none are checked for each group.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Your problem description is unclear.  **By default**, applying the `required` rule to a group of checkboxes will make sure at least one is checked.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/XqPn2/

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML of the form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By creating a new attribute to each of my groups I was able to solve it when the user tries to submit the form:

The attribute added was `data-foo="anynameyouwantforyourgroup"`

```
$('#docContainer').submit(function() {
    if ($('[data-foo=property]:checked').size() == 0)
    {
        alert('You must CHECK at least 1 option for group X');
        return false;
    }

    if ($('[data-foo=bedrooms]:checked').size() == 0) {
        alert('You must CHECK at least 1 option for group Y');
        return false;
    }

    if ($('[data-foo=price]:checked').size() == 0) {
        alert('You must CHECK at least 1 option for group Z');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here.  Because, by default, applying the `required` rule to a group of checkboxes will make sure at least one is checked.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/Nvu83/

Comment: @Sparky because the groups have random names so I would have to check if one of the check boxes that have id X is on the name is check or not for group 1, then same for group 2 and 3 with different id's, like I have explained and showed on the question.

Comment: @Sparky here is an example based on your jsfiddle with the above mentioned groups http://jsfiddle.net/42PrP/3/ which I cannot rename as mentioned if u wish to see a better solution to it. I cannot change the name, id or class attributes.

Comment: You failed to show the HTML in your OP.  Without the HTML, we can't see how your groups were constructed.

Comment: @Sparky Oh yes I am sorry that giving you the names of each checkbox and how they are grouped fails your concept.

Answer (score 0):

**By default**, the jQuery Validate plugin will automatically make sure at least one checkbox in a group is checked.  You simply need to apply the `required` rule to the group.

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            checkboxGroup1: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            checkboxGroup1: {
                required: "you must check at least one from Group 1"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup1" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup1" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup1" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/42PrP/